# Convert XeLaTeX to ePub

Tags: xetex, debugging, bugs, epub

**Hi all,**

I have a XeLaTeX file which once compiled gives that kind of pdf page :

[image]

What I need is to have from the tex file an **ePub format** instead of the pdf one.

So before posting all this message, I tried some solutions I could find on the web like Pandoc, latexml, and others I don't remember.
But for each one I got an error.
So maybe, you could help me to resolve theses errors or maybe you could help me with a new tool to get ePub format I didn't know.

**To have an idea of what looks like the XeLateX code, here it's a good preview (MWE) :**

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \title{{\myfont ``GA 032''}}
 \usepackage{layout}
 \usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
 \pagestyle{plain}

 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{greek}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{KoineGreek}
\newcommand\Pheader{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.7pt}}
 % amélioration : ajouter un "padding" sur le tabular + agrandir le tabular et son contenu.

\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother
\let\oldtabular\tabular\renewcommand{\tabular}{\large\selectfont\oldtabular} %fontsize{17pt}{20.5pt}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{gospelbook}
\setcounter{gospelbook}{1}
\newcommand{\mygospelbook}[1]
{\setcounter{gospelchapter}{1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}#1}


\newcommand{\agospelbook}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}\mygospelbook{#1}}

\newcounter{gospelchapter}
\newcommand{\mygospelchapter}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thegospelchapter}\LARGE\bfseries\thegospelchapter\refstepcounter{gospelchapter}}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt 
%\layout
 \maketitle % affiche le nom du manuscrit.
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\foreignlanguage{greek}{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\clearpage
\newpage
 {
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|l|ccc}
\cline{4-4} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{4-4} \\
\cline{4-4}
&  &  & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  &  \\
&  & 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} &  \\
&  & 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  &  \\
&  & 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  &  \\
&  & 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} &  \\
&  & 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον φαρεϲ και τον ζαρα} & 8 &  &  \\
&  & 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκ τηϲ θαμαρ φαρεϲ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  &  \\
&  & 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζρωμ εζρωμ δε εγεννηϲεν το̅} & 20 &  &  \\
&  & 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αραμ αραμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αμινα} & 5 & \textbf{4} &  \\
&  & 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαβ αμιναδαβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον} & 9 &  &  \\
&  & 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νααϲϲων νααϲϲων δε εγεννηϲε̅} & 13 &  &  \\
&  & 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαλμων ϲαλμων δε εγεννηϲε̅} & 3 & \textbf{5} &  \\
&  & 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον βοοζ εκ τηϲ ραχαβ βοοζ δε εγε̅} & 11 &  &  \\
&  & 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ωβηδ εκ τηϲ ρουθ ωβηδ} & 17 &  &  \\
&  & 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δε εγεννηϲεν τον ειεϲϲαι ιεϲϲαι δε} & 2 & \textbf{6} &  \\
&  & 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον δαυειδ τον βαϲιλεα} & 7 &  &  \\
&  & 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαυειδ δε ο βαϲιλευϲ εγεννηϲεν το̅} & 13 &  &  \\
&  & 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲολομωντα εκ τηϲ του ουριου ϲολο} & 1 & \textbf{7} &  \\
&  & 1 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μων δε εγεννηϲεν τον ροβοαμ} & 5 &  &  \\
&  & 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ροβοαμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αβια αβι} & 11 &  &  \\
&  & 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{α δε εγεννηϲεν τον αϲα αϲα δε εγε̅} & 3 & \textbf{8} &  \\
&  & 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ιωϲαφατ ιωϲαφατ δε} & 7 &  &  \\
&  & 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον ιωραμ ιωραμ δε εγε̅} & 13 &  &  \\
&  & 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον οζειαν οζειαϲ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{9} &  \\
&  & 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωαθαμ ιωαθαμ δε εγεννη} & 9 &  &  \\
&  & 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αχαζ αχαζ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  &  \\
&  & 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζεκιαν εζεκιαϲ δε εγεννηϲε̅} & 3 & \textbf{10} &  \\
&  & 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον μαναϲϲη μαναϲηϲ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  &  \\
&  & 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αμων αμων δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  &  \\
&  & 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ιωϲιαν ιωϲιαϲ δε εγεννηϲεν το̅} & 4 & \textbf{11} &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{4-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

**Here is some errors I could have with the previous tools I used :**

*I'm using **macOS Mojave** 10.14.6*

- *Pandoc (v 2.7.3)* :

```
Error at "source" (line 68, column 65):
unexpected \rule
& \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  &  \\
```

- *text4ht* (didn't find the version number but it should be the last one normaly) :

```
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht test.tex 
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `test.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `test.dvi'
```

- I don't remember from where I got this error :

```
Can't locate Alien/Libxml2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Alien::Libxml2 module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0) at Makefile.PL line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 20.
```

- When I did `perl Makefile.PL` on Makefile.PL from the LaTeXML folder to install *latexml*.

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/bin/perl" -MParse::RecDescent - lib/LaTeXML/MathGrammar LaTeXML::MathGrammar Parse::RecDescent
Can't locate Parse/RecDescent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Parse::RecDescent module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/lib/perl5/5.26.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.1/lib/perl5/5.26.1 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26.1).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
make: *** [blib/lib/LaTeXML/MathGrammar.pm] Error 2
```

- When I try to execute *latexml* (didn't find the version number but it should be the last one normaly):

```
Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::LibXML module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/bin/../lib /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.30.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.0) at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Common/Object.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Common/Object.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Common/Error.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Common/Error.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Core.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/lib/perl5/LaTeXML/Core.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/bin/latexml line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/latexml/0.8.4/libexec/bin/latexml line 19.
```

- When I try with the software called SimpleTeX4ht (v 3.3) :

```
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.28 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort.
|...............................................
```

**Thanks for every help !**

Answer (score 2):

Your document compiles without problems with `tex4ht`, you just need to provide a small configuration file and require the `XeTeX` support, which is not used by default. As you want an ePub file, you can use `tex4ebook` which is LaTeX to Ebook converter based on `tex4ht`. I've found an additional issue that doesn't affect `tex4ht` itself, but does affect `tex4ebook`.

I had to modify your document slightly, in particular I moved the definition of `\myfont` before its first use:

```
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt
\title{{\myfont ``GA 032''}}
```

It is necessary to declare used Unicode blocks for the `tex4ht` XeTeX support,
so I've created a configuration file that adds support for Greek:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\nofrench@punctuation%
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

The `\nofrench@punctuation` fixes a `tex4ebook` issue with active characters used in the TOC.

The document can be converted using:

```
tex4ebook -xc config.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I have the following error when I compile with your solution :
`! Undefined control sequence.  
l.2 \xeuniuseblock  
                  {Greek}
?`
Your post gave me unexpected hope, thanks!

Comment: @gustav.b which TeX distribution do you use? It should work in TL 2019 and TL 2018.

Comment: I get this when I type `tex -v` : TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) . So I'm going to see if I can update tex.

Comment: @gustav.b ah, that is a really old distribution. it would be best to update it, if it is possible.

Comment: It works, yes. But would you know how I could have my personal font KoineGreek in this final ePub ?

Comment: @gustav.b sure, see the documentation in progress here: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc/blob/master/sections/webfonts.tex I guess you will need also some CSS to make it work